# Add argument start method JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, arguments

How pass argument in the start method in application javafx ?
In fact, I call my javafx application in an other class by the line :

```
mainController.getMainApp().launch(MainApp.class);
```

And below my start method :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("CLS");
    this.primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    // here the page fxml to load
```

The problem is that I don't know after what is the page fxml i will load in my start method. It's in my another class who know. 
So I want to pass argument in my method start to know what fxml page I will load.

Help please.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have somewhat misunderstood the life cycle of a JavaFX application. The `Application` class just represents the entire application and the `start()` method is invoked to start it: think of `start()` as essentially a replacement for `main()`. Consequently, the only data that should be available when `start()` is invoked are the command line parameters passed to the application from the command line. Other than the stage passed to the `start()` method, there should be no other accessible objects in memory at all at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`launch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) method of `Application` is designed to accept varargs argument:

```
public static void launch(Class<? extends Application> appClass, String... args)
```

Therefore you can pass arguments like:

```
launch(MainApp.class, "--FXMLFile=Sample.fxml", "UnnamedArgument");
```

Then in the [`init`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#init--) or in the [`start`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start-javafx.stage.Stage-) method you can get these arguments by using [`getParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--) method:

```
Parameters parameters = getParameters();
List<String> unnamed = parameters.getUnnamed();
Map<String, String> named = parameters.getNamed();
List<String> raw = parameters.getRaw();
```

You can use named or unnamed parameters (in the example the first one is named the second one is unnamed. The [`getNamed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html#getNamed--) method returns the named parameters in a `Map`, the [`getUnnamed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html#getUnnamed--) method returns the unnamed parameters in a `List`, while [`getRaw()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html#getRaw--) returns the named and unnamed parameters as a raw `list`.

*Note from the javadoc of getParameters():*

> NOTE: this method should not be called from the Application
>   constructor, as it will return null. I**t may be called in the init()
>   method or any time after that.**

Comment: Okey thanks, but if I write a launch method, I have not access to the primaryStage who is init is in the method start ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Benj You don't write the `launch(...)` method; it is already written for you. You just call it from `main(...)` in case the JRE doesn't know how to launch a JavaFX application itself. It looks like you are trying to start your application in the wrong place.